# CKEditor - Leading <p>&nbsp;</p> that I want rid of

Tags: ckeditor

When I use the editor and type "test" I get back the following:

```
"<html data-version="ckeditor"><body><p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:11pt"><span style="font-size:11pt">test</span></span></span></p>
</body></html>"
```

The problem is the `<p>&nbsp;</p>`. I have no idea why its there but it is adding an empty line at the top when the value is saved/opened again.

I have tried various config settings:

```
config.autoParagraph = false;
config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV;
```

But none of them work. I cant see why its being added, Its completely unnecessary.

Can anyone tell me how I set it up so they don't get added through the config, if theres a way, or just let me know if there is not.

Answer (score 0):

It's really strange markup which you receive from the CKEditor. I've build some example codepen, where implement standard CKEditor setup. Below editor is button which triggers receiving data from editor.

https://codepen.io/msamsel/pen/GMEqyo/

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
editor.getData();
```

Usually [`getData`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getData) method should be used to obtain data from editor.

I hope this example will help. If not then, can you give more info what kind of CKEditor setup do you use and which version?

Comment: Actually autoParagraph = false works. Our build script works quite weirdly with CKEditor so it wasnt being picked up. The change had to go into client/core/editor.js to actually have it picked up and working.